# angular2 http.delete on in-memory-web-api

Tags: http, angular, typescript, angular-cli, in-memory-database

my project uses on premise servers, the backend runs on .NET core and  I develop on a mac, so I cannot run an instance of our backend. Therefore I have made a separate (angular-cli) environment for my project that uses the in-memory-web-api.

I have it set up and works for get/ and get/:id. but a delete won't work. Is there any way to make this work or is it not possible to do it with i-m-w-a ?

The Service

```
public getOperations(): Observable<IOperation[]>{
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}operations/`)
        .map(this.sharedService.extractData)
        .catch(this.sharedService.handleError);
  }
  public getOperation(operationId: string):Observable<IOperation>{
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}operations/${operationId}`)
        .map(this.sharedService.extractData)
        .catch(this.sharedService.handleError);
  }
  public deleteOperation(operationId: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(`${environment.baseUrl}operations/${operationId}`)
        .map(this.sharedService.extractData)
        .catch(this.sharedService.handleError);
  }
```

The In memory database

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let operations: IOperation[] = [
            new Operation({
                id:'001',
                name: 'Operation ABC',
                status:'Active',
                startDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
            }),
            new Operation({
                id:'002',
                name: 'Operation DEF',
                status:'Closed',
                startDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
                endDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
            }),
            new Operation({
                id:'003',
                name: 'Operation GHI',
                status:'Closed',
                startDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
                endDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
            }),
            new Operation({
                id:'004',
                name: 'Operation JKL',
                status:'Closed',
                startDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
                endDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
            }),
        ];
        return {operations};
    }
}
```

Forgot to add my component method that calls my service method:

```
public deleteOperation(operation: IOperation){
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: `Are you sure that you want to delete '${operation.name}'?`,
            accept: () => {
                this.operationsService.deleteOperation(operation.id)
                    .subscribe(()=>{
                        this.loadOperations();
                    })
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the problem, 
I removed the .map function from my deleteOperation service method.
the extractData did a res.json(), which didn't work, therefore it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You must `.subscribe()` to the `Observable` returned from `deleteOperation()` in order to for `http` to carry out the request. Otherwise, an API call will not be made.

Comment: forgot to add my component function, added it here now, I do call .subscribe on it the loadoperations is a method that does the getOperations call again